Finding regular expressions for symmetric language
I have a question in my exam about Automata: "Let L be a language of symmetric words created by the alphabet Σ = {a, b}, the language expressed by which expression below contain words in language L?
A. (a*+b*)*
B. a* b* b* a*
C. (baab)*
D. All answers are wrong."
I think the answer is C since we have words such as: baab, baabbaab, baabbaabbaab, ... these are all symmetric words - reading from left to right is the same as reading right to left. But in the answer sheet of my teacher, he chose A as the correct answer. Did he give wrong answer? Thank you

C is the only of the three languages contained in $L$, if that's the question. If the question is which one is equivalent to $L$, it's D ($L$'s not even a regular language). If the question is which language contains $L$, then the answer is $A$. It's completely unclear to me from the wording which of these three options is intended.

Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/169802/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/79012821/781723. Please do not post the same question on multiple sites.

Our goal is to create an archive of knowledge that will be useful to others in the future.  I don't think this question is likely to be useful to others in the future ... especially when the issue arises because the problem statement is ambiguous (and hence your question is ambiguous).  We can't read your teacher's mind, and if you are asking a question here, it's your responsibility to make sure your question here is unambiguous.

I see that others already gave feedback that the question is unambiguous, before you posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79012821/finding-regular-expressions-for-symmetric-language#comment139316410_79012821.  I think it would have been better to have addressed that feedback by revising the question before posting here.

I read the question as asking whether the language described by the expression contains any words in L, i.e. whether the intersection of the two languages is nonempty.

Alternative D is self-referential.
